# Pass variable to included layout via xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I want to include a simple layout and pass a static variable to it (string resource here). I [followed](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes) [multiple](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-that-include-thing-1c8791dd6038) [examples](https://mobikul.com/imports-includes-data-binding/) with no luck.

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data></data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include android:id="@+id/first_included" layout="@layout/included" app:theValue="@string/firstValue" />
        <include android:id="@+id/first_included" layout="@layout/included" app:theValue="@string/secondValue" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

included.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable name="theValue" type="String" />
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{theValue}"/>    
</layout>
```

This gives me the compile error

> Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'theValue' in
>   package 'com.just.example'

I do use databinding in the rest of the project and everything works fine. I could set the value programmatically but this one is static, I want to be able to set it in the layout file.

Comment: Try using a data binding expression for `app:theValue` (e.g., `app:theValue="@{@string/firstValue}"`).

Comment: I did try doing this earlier but failed, the problem is that I have my resources dot-separated which throws a compile error with your suggestion.. Maybe dot-separated resources aren't that well supported. Thank you, it worked like that without a dot-separated resource. Doh..

Comment: Please check this code: DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, yourView); in your activity. I think you missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In general you have to assign a data binding statement to the attribute you want to use it with. If the attribute itself is well supported with the default XML definitions, it won't fail. But when there's no definition for the attribute (other than the explicit and implicit ones with data binding), the attribute can't be handled and you'll find the error you got.

So whenever you use data binding specific attributes like with the variables of an included layout, you need to define it as

```
app:myAttr="@{...}"
```

The [Expression Language](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#expression_language) itself has some nice shortcuts for resources defined. So in you case you can just `@string/firstValue` inside your expression. This will be resolved to a `String` which is in turn assigned to the variable `theValue` in your sublayout.